# Partitions to be backed up and restored to prevent losing data after bootloader unlock?

Tags: 9.0-pie, bootloader-lock

I have a device running Android 9.0 Pie with a **locked bootloader** running unmodified stock firmware. The *userdata* partition on the device is currently encrypted using **Full Disk Encryption** (FDE) with the **default password** (I have not used the option to encrypt the device with a lock screen password.)

There exists a loophole in this firmware which allows me to **create images of entire partitions** of the device (by copying a block device from `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/`) and save them on a PC. I have tested this on the *cache* partition and I was able to successfully mount and browse the copied image as an *ext4* partition under Linux.
**Note:** I don't have root access on the running system, so I cannot directly access decrypted files under */data*, so this method is out of question.

Now, I wish to **unlock the bootloader** which will wipe the *userdata* partition and reset the device.

Which all **partitions should be backed-up before unlocking the bootloader** and restored after the unlock, so that the device will be able to successfully decrypt the *userdata* partition and boot normally (or at least a custom recovery like TWRP will be able to decrypt the partition) ?

The [Android Source documentation for FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk#storing_the_encrypted_key) states that the key is stored in the *Crypto metadata*, which is located either inside the *userdata* partition itself or in a separate *metadata* partition.
Here is a list of partitions present on the device :-

```
ImageFv -> /dev/block/sdf4
abl_a -> /dev/block/sde32
abl_b -> /dev/block/sde33
aop_a -> /dev/block/sde14
aop_b -> /dev/block/sde15
apdp -> /dev/block/sde6
bk01 -> /dev/block/sda3
bk02 -> /dev/block/sda4
bk03 -> /dev/block/sda5
bk04 -> /dev/block/sda8
bk05 -> /dev/block/sda13
bk31 -> /dev/block/sdd1
bk32 -> /dev/block/sdd3
bk33 -> /dev/block/sdd5
bk41 -> /dev/block/sde3
bk42 -> /dev/block/sde9
bk43 -> /dev/block/sde16
bk44 -> /dev/block/sde17
bk45 -> /dev/block/sde25
bk46 -> /dev/block/sde29
bk47 -> /dev/block/sde38
bk48 -> /dev/block/sde40
bk49 -> /dev/block/sde41
bk51 -> /dev/block/sdf2
bk52 -> /dev/block/sdf3
bk53 -> /dev/block/sdf5
bluetooth -> /dev/block/sde24
boot -> /dev/block/sde45
cache -> /dev/block/sda20
cdt -> /dev/block/sdd2
cmnlib64_a -> /dev/block/sde20
cmnlib64_b -> /dev/block/sde21
cmnlib_a -> /dev/block/sde18
cmnlib_b -> /dev/block/sde19
cust -> /dev/block/sda18
ddr -> /dev/block/sdd4
devcfg_a -> /dev/block/sde12
devcfg_b -> /dev/block/sde13
devinfo -> /dev/block/sda12
dip -> /dev/block/sde28
dsp -> /dev/block/sde44
dtbo -> /dev/block/sde37
frp -> /dev/block/sda7
fsc -> /dev/block/sdf1
fsg -> /dev/block/sde36
hyp_a -> /dev/block/sde26
hyp_b -> /dev/block/sde27
keymaster_a -> /dev/block/sde22
keymaster_b -> /dev/block/sde23
keystore -> /dev/block/sda6
limits -> /dev/block/sde2
logdump -> /dev/block/sda16
logfs -> /dev/block/sda10
logo -> /dev/block/sde43
minidump -> /dev/block/sda17
misc -> /dev/block/sda9
modem -> /dev/block/sde46
modemst1 -> /dev/block/sdf6
modemst2 -> /dev/block/sdf7
msadp -> /dev/block/sde7
oops -> /dev/block/sda11
persist -> /dev/block/sda14
persistbak -> /dev/block/sda15
qupfw_a -> /dev/block/sde4
qupfw_b -> /dev/block/sde5
recovery -> /dev/block/sda19
sec -> /dev/block/sde1
splash -> /dev/block/sde42
spunvm -> /dev/block/sde39
ssd -> /dev/block/sda2
sti -> /dev/block/sde30
storsec_a -> /dev/block/sde10
storsec_b -> /dev/block/sde11
switch -> /dev/block/sda1
system -> /dev/block/sde48
toolsfv -> /dev/block/sde31
tz_a -> /dev/block/sde34
tz_b -> /dev/block/sde35
userdata -> /dev/block/sda21
vbmeta -> /dev/block/sde8
vendor -> /dev/block/sde47
xbl_a -> /dev/block/sdb2
xbl_b -> /dev/block/sdc2
xbl_config_a -> /dev/block/sdb1
xbl_config_b -> /dev/block/sdc1
```

Note that the *metadata* partition is not present.

### ------------------------- UPDATE -------------------------

(based on the comments by @[alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470))

#### FSTAB entry

I extracted the *fstab.qcom* file from the device firmware image (*/vendor/etc/fstab.qcom*) and here is the relevant line (the full fstab is [here](https://pastebin.com/NSVMH47B))  -

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /data ext4 noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,noauto_da_alloc wait,check,reservedsize=128M,forceencrypt=footer,quota
```

#### android_bruteforce_stdcrypto

I ran the [python script from Santoku's repository](https://github.com/santoku/Santoku-Linux/blob/master/tools/android/android_bruteforce_stdcrypto/bruteforce_stdcrypto.py) on the header (first 512 bytes) and footer (last 16KB) extracted from the *userdata* image, and got this output (private data is concealed) -

```
Android FDE crypto footer
-------------------------
Magic          : 0xXXXXXXXX
Major Version  : 1
Minor Version  : 3
Footer Size    : 2352 bytes
Flags          : 0x00001000
Key Size       : 128 bits
Failed Decrypts: 0
Crypto Type    : aes-xts
Encrypted Key  : 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Salt           : 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
KDF            : scrypt
N_factor       : 15     (N=32768)
r_factor       : 3      (r=8)
p_factor       : 1      (p=2)
-------------------------
```

So, now that I have enough evidence about all the encryption data being present in the *userdata* partition itself, I am going to proceed by backing up and restoring **only the *userdata* partition** after the bootloader unlock.

I will update this with an answer containing my results after unlocking.

Comment: if flag in fstab is forceencrypt=footer then it is last -16384 bytes of userdata, otherwise there is path to file or partition. to double check you can run [bruteforce_stdcrypto.py](https://santoku-linux.com/howto/mobile-forensics/how-to-brute-force-android-encryption/#run-brute-force), it is impossible to decrypt but it will reveal Android FDE crypto footer is valid

Comment: Hello @alecxs and thank you for responding. Please have a look at the updated question. Unfortunately, I won't be able to try the _patched-image injection_ that you suggested. I have read online that the EDL mode on my device model is protected by some proprietary manufacturer authorisation. Moreover, to start EDL mode, I will have to dismantle the device (which I am not willing to do at least currently).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBE encryption bootloader state in keys](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/fbe-encryption-bootloader-state-in-keys)