# Recover data from a phone that says decryption unsuccessful

Tags: recovery-mode, oneplus

I have a OnePlus device which is setup with face unlock, fingerprint and pattern unlock. Non rooted, stock Oxygen 10 and stock recovery. Locked bootloader.

My phone recently froze while unlocking and after a reboot it now says decryption unsuccessful. I seek some help in figuring out what my options are from here on. What must I do, so that I do not loose my data?

1. Will it be possible to perform a device dump from fastboot/adb and flash it to a similar device with similar pattern lock and get my files back?
2. Is there a way to backup the /data (apps, books, pictures, music) from fastboot/adb and have them decrypted in some other way? Or pull /data from adb/fastboot, reset phone and reflash the /data and hope for decryption?
3. Can I reset my phone without losing data?
4. Or should I reflash the stock OS?

Any pointers will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Encrypted user data dumps are encrypted with a key that is bound to the chip in your phone. An identical phone can has a different key and thus can not decrypt the dump.

Comment: So can we fetch this key assuming I dump my data and rest my phone, and them attempt to decrypt the dump on my same device?

Comment: The key is bound to the hardware chip and the installed OS. You can use it on the device but extraction is not possible as this is not supported by the installed OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBE encryption bootloader state in keys](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/fbe-encryption-bootloader-state-in-keys)