# Decrypt Android FDE /data partition with lost locksettings.db

Tags: disk-encryption

So let's assume I am on Android 9 and have the encrypted FDE `/data` partition and the full `/system` partition - except for `locksettings.db`. I also know the pass code used to decrypt/unlock the device after rebooting. On a fresh installation it looks like the database only contains the identifier of the key but the key seems to be located in a file within the `/system` partition, which is intact.

Now my question is: Is there any way to decrypt the partition or reconstruct the `locksettings.db` file? I would be very grateful for any help with the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: It booted, unlocked without a code, but displayed the "Phone is starting up..." message it usually shows for a few seconds when decrypting - forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does FBE's key derivation work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216155/how-exactly-does-fbes-key-derivation-work)

Comment: [OnePlus 5T](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3715834) is running [FBE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232224) file-based encryption, below answer does not apply

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to decrypt userdata partition offline. Android encryption is hardware-backed with RSA-2048 masterkey in TEE that is burned to chip. Furthermore encryption is bonded to

```
VENDOR_PATCH_LEVEL
BOOT_PATCH_LEVEL
OS_PATCH_LEVEL
OS_VERSION
```

and
bootloader state
to ensure *rollback protection* and tamper protection.

If your bootloader is already unlocked, crypto-footer is present in EFS/metadata and userdata is encrypted with *"default_password"* it is possible to decrypt from custom recovery TWRP without `locksettings.db` at all (except Samsung)

Comment: That is interesting information I didn't see before. I will try reproducing the exact same environment (firmware, ROM etc.) and see if I'm successful in decrypting the partition without `locksettings.db`. I'm using a OnePlus 5T, so maybe there was another issue last time I tried.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I don't have the exact OS version and patch I had when I set up the encryption, it won't be able to decrypt?

Comment: no, only on same or higher patch level