# Question about FDE without secure start up and factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, encryption

So I read that on device launching with 7.0 , it has FDE by default and a 256 bit primary key is randomly generated at first booting the device (say after a factory reset).

My question is, if no secure start up was set up and the primary key is encrypted by "default password" only, is the primary key still "lost" after a subsequent factory reset?

If so,

Will default fde without secure start up still prevent the device data from being accessed after a second factory reset that loses the first primary key?

Comment: factory reset always erase crypto footer. if it's lost, you are lost

Comment: As far as I remember "secure startup" is something only Samsung devices have, so your device is a one from Samsung?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypt Android FDE /data partition with lost locksettings.db](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241581/decrypt-android-fde-data-partition-with-lost-locksettings-db)