# Retrieve data from locked android

Tags: data-recovery, locked-out

I have my old phone (Huawei P9 Lite - according to the Internet it's Android 8.0 Oreo), but I don't remember the PIN code. I need to download data (photos) from this phone. As far as I know, Android does not encrypt the data by default.

1. How to check if the phone is encrypted or not?
2. If the phone is encrypted, how to download the photos from it?
3. If the phone is *not* encrypted, how to download the photos from it?
4. Is it possible to bypass the PIN code and access the photos somehow?

Maybe there are some Windows or Kali Linux programs to do it?

Comment: If the phone comes with Android 8 then it should be encrypted by default. Does the PIN code dialog look like the lock screen PIN dialog or does it looks different (simpler)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering data from Mi 4c able to get only to fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/recovering-data-from-mi-4c-able-to-get-only-to-fastboot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBE encryption bootloader state in keys](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/fbe-encryption-bootloader-state-in-keys)

Comment: You have to guess the code. There's no work around to it.